# Control page scroll animation with mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

can anybody help me understand how Honda achieved this effect:
http://testdays.hondamoto.ch/

I mean the ease when you scroll.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var $pages = $(".page"),
    tot = $pages.length,
    c = 0, pagePos = 0, down = 0, listen = true;

$('html, body').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!listen)return;
  
  listen = false;
  
  down = e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0;
  c = Math.min(Math.max(0, down ? ++c : --c), tot-1);
  pagePos = $pages.eq(c).offset().top;  
  
  $(this).stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos}, 650, function(){
    listen = true;
  });
  
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
.page{min-height:100vh;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page" style="background:#0bf">PAGE 1</div>
<div class="page" style="background:#fb0">PAGE 2</div>
<div class="page" style="background:#0fb">PAGE 3</div>
<div class="page" style="background:#b0f">PAGE 4</div>
```

**P.S:**
Use `.position().top;` if your `.page`s are inside a scrollable DIV like `$("#pagesParent")` (instead of `$('html, body')`)

---

**Notice:**
for **mobile** you might want to adjust the value accounting for the browser's tabs bar height (or best, prevent that behaviour at all). You got the idea

Comment: Oh great, thank you - how can I add some kind of a easing slow in fast out for example.

Comment: @user1464175 You're welcome. Just change from my code `'easeInCirc'` to some other easing from the list I gave you in my answer

Comment: oooh i am sorry didn't see it, i was so happy that i clicked right away on the fiddle. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how can i connect your script with button navigation - when i put a navigation in my side, it scrolls on its own, that means when i scroll through a button to a slide, the scroll event does not remember that position but its own so it scroll to a totaly different slide.

Comment: Very simple: you see the `var c` remembers the current slide. The only thing you need to do is: on button click do `++c` or `--c` like the mousewheel does! I'll setup a demo

Comment: Here you go! After you remove the comments from the script you'll see how nice and easy it is! : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/r3x7r/3/

Comment: oh - that makes sense, so c remembers the current slide, and with c++ or c-- i got one slide further or back, but how do i go two slides further or three etc? Now when the script remembers on which page i am, i am probably able to hover the active button right?

Comment: oh i got it working that it slides 2 pages, but not to a specific one.

Comment: Hmm why would you slide 2 pages? And how? you have more buttons than prev-next? like a go-to-page-N buttons?

Comment: well, i actually need a button that slides to a specific page like you said got-to-page-N, therefor you need a button that slides more pages i thought but i actually need a button that slides to page N. and yes i would have mor buttons like "Page1" "Page2" "page3" "page4" and every button slides to this page and should get active like onepage navigations do, i know how to code those navigations sliding to a div with an id but not in this case

Comment: hey rook, i got everything working - i changed the code so i have 12 fixed buttons and not auto generated like in your code, this way it was easier for me to style this buttons(normal and hover) - and this is the last thing i don't get, how do i add an active state to the buttons so i can see on which page i am actually are. i hope so much that you can help me again - but so far a reaaaaally big thank you to you.

Comment: @user1464175 I think you're doing it wrong if you don't auto-generate your buttons, you're just giving your self future headaches. Let the code generate buttons for you. Here is a demo with active class: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/r3x7r/28/

Comment: you are probably right, the thing is, i got a hover state and this hover state is a kind of a tooltip and every buttons needs to have different text within the tooltip therefor i need 12 different classes  but the code only generates one <button class=".."></button> tag and not 12 different ones..i sure there is a way to solve it with auto-generate, but I'm a beginner and for the tool tip i just hide/show a div (every button has another div) on mouseover - it works for me :D and a really big thank you to you rook you helped me a lot.

Comment: hi roko, another question. Right know i come to the next page when i scroll one tick but when i scroll 3 ticks i come to page 3. Is its possible to change code the way that it doesn't matter how many ticks i scroll but always come to the next slide an not to the third ? thank you.

Comment: :) haaha fair player! here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/r3x7r/102/ it's all well commented.

Comment: hi roko, i changed your code, so ecery page fades in, but how does it work with fading out again, i changed this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5Md/

Comment: This is great - can it be modified to work the arrow keys as well? So that the up and down keys will work the same way scrolling up or down works?

Comment: @roXon - and is there a way to add an active class to the current section? Maybe in a way which would allow you to start in section 2 on load for example?

Comment: @KasperBjerre sure there is! Edit my demos (the ones from the comments above), add a HASH on link click, read if there's a hash on page load and scroll to it. If you get the logic out from code - it should be really easy for you to make the "arrows" work. just replace "Prev" and "next" with some arrows :) I you don't see any prev-next that's cause I forgot to add a z-index of those elements.

Comment: @roXon - thank you for your quick reply!
I have tried adding `id="active"` to the second section and then I go to it on load with  `$(window).load(function() { 
$(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#active").offset().top );  
});
});` But then the first time I scroll down it does not work properly - I think it is because I have to scroll past the sections above it before I can scroll to the one below?

Answer (score 1):

Open up their JS file : http://testdays.hondamoto.ch/js/script_2.js

and search for Utils - Navigation

```
/***********************************************************************************************/
/************************************  Utils - Navigation  *************************************/
/***********************************************************************************************/
/**
 * navigation
 */
function navigation(target){
    //--Init Quiz
    if(!quizRdy){
        hideQuiz();
    }

    //Add class to body
    var pageName = target.substr(1).split('-');
    $('body').removeClass(lastPage);
    $('body').addClass(pageName[0]);
    lastPage = pageName[0];

    if(resizeBg)retractBg();
    resizeBg = false;
    busy = true;
    $('body').addClass('loading');

    //Change Nav Color
    $('#nav-wrapper ul.nav li a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    var currentNavNumber = currentNav +1;
    $('#main_nav_'+currentNavNumber).addClass('selected')

    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    if(wHeight<1080){
        var newMargin = 180 - ( (wHeight - 720)/2 ) ;
        if(newMargin<0) newMargin=180;
    }else{
        var newMargin =0 - (wHeight - 1080)/2;
    }

    var navTop = $(target).offset().top + newMargin;
    navTop += 'px';
    trace('navTop : '+navTop);
    //$('#nav-wrapper').css('top',navTop);

    $('html,body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top + newMargin
    }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo',function(){
        trace('annime done - wHeight : '+wHeight+' target top : '+$(target).offset().top);

        if(currentNav==2 && !quizRdy && !quizForm){
            showQuiz();
        }
        if(currentNav==4){
            //update social datas
            $.getJSON('inc/socials.php', function(data) {
                $('#count-fans').empty().append(data['fans-count']);
                $('#count-followers').empty().append(data['followers-count']);
            });
        }
        /*
        if(currentNav==2){
            $('#quiz-nav').livequery(function(){
                $(this).show();
            });
        }else{
            $('#quiz-nav').livequery(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
        */
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
        if(currentNav!=0 && currentNav!=4){
            $('#nav-wrapper').fadeIn(200);
        }else{
            $('#nav-wrapper').fadeOut(200);
        }
        if(currentNav==3){
            //--Init Google Map
            if(!mapReady){
                if(dealerReady){
                    //init map
                    initialize();
                }else{
                    askMap = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(wHeight>1080){
            extendBg();
        }
        busy = false;
    });
}

/**
 * navigation next Page
 */
function nextPage(){
    if(currentNav<navArray.length-1 && !busy){ 
        currentNav++;   
        navigation(navArray[currentNav]);
    }
}
/**
 * navigation previous Page
 */
function prevPage(){
    if(currentNav>0 && !busy){ 
        currentNav--;   
        navigation(navArray[currentNav]);
    }
}

/**
 *  Center content
 */
function centerContent(){
    if(!busy){
        //--Retract Background if expended for big screen
        if(resizeBg)retractBg();

        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var imgHeight = 0;

        //--Test image width / Height and fill the screen 
        if(wWidth / wHeight > ratioImg ){
            //trace('case1 -   width : ' + wWidth + '   height : '+wHeight);
            if(wHeight > 1080 || wWidth > 1900){
                var newImgHeight = wWidth * 1080 / 1920;
                $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'height':newImgHeight+'px',
                        'width':'100%'
                    });
                });
                imgHeight = newImgHeight;
            }else{
                $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'height':'1080px',
                        'width':'1900px'
                    });
                });
                imgHeight = 1080;
            }
        }else{
            if(wHeight > 1080 || wWidth > 1900){
                $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                    var newImgWidth = wHeight * 1920 / 1080;
                    $(this).css({
                        'height':wHeight+'px',
                        'width':newImgWidth+'px'
                    });
                });
                imgHeight = wHeight;
            }else{
                $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'height':'1080px',
                        'width':'1900px'
                    });
                });
                imgHeight = 1080;
            }
        }
        //--Fix height if window > img height
        if(wHeight>imgHeight){
            $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                var newImgWidth = wHeight * 1920 / 1080;
                $(this).css({
                    'height':wHeight+'px',
                    'width':newImgWidth+'px'
                });
            });
        }
        //--Center horizontal bkg image
        if(wWidth<1900){
            $(".bg-image").each(function(){
                var marginCenter = (wWidth - 1900) / 2;
                marginCenter = marginCenter * -1;
                if($(this).width() > (wWidth + marginCenter)){
                    $(this).css({'margin-left':-marginCenter+'px'});
                }
            });
        }
        //--Scroll to the good position
        if(wHeight<1080){
            var newMargin = 180 - ( (wHeight - 720)/2 ) ;
            if(newMargin<0) newMargin=180;
        }else{
            var newMargin =0 - (wHeight - 1080)/2;
        }
        var navTop =$(navArray[currentNav]).offset().top + newMargin;
        navTop += 'px';
        //$('#nav-wrapper').css('top',navTop);
        //trace('Scrool to good position, then expend bg : ' + navArray[currentNav] + '  '+ $(navArray[currentNav]).offset().top);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(navArray[currentNav]).offset().top + newMargin
        }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo',function(){
            if(wHeight>1080){
                extendBg();
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 *  Extend the background image for big screen ( > 1080 px )
 */
function extendBg(){
    var hWin = $(window).height();
    if(hWin > 1080){
        //--Get & save current page Name
        lastBg = navArray[currentNav].split('-');
        lastBg = lastBg[0].substr(1);
        lastheight = $('#bg-'+lastBg).height();
        //--Calculate the position from top to set the scroll position
        posToTop = (hWin - $('#bg-'+lastBg).height())/2;
        posToTop = $('#bg-'+lastBg).offset().top - posToTop;
        lastPosToTop = $('#bg-'+lastBg).offset().top;
        //trace('posToTop setting : '+posToTop+' page : ' + lastBg);
        //--Set boolean resize to true to call the retract BG
        resizeBg = true;
        $('#bg-'+lastBg).css({'z-index':2});
        //--Test if it's first or last
        if(currentNav != 0 && currentNav != (navArray.length-1)){
            $('#bg-'+lastBg).animate({
                height:hWin+'px',
                top:posToTop+'px'
            },600);
        }else{
            if(currentNav==0){
                posToTop=0;
                $('#bg-'+lastBg).animate({
                    height:hWin+'px',
                    top:0
                },600);
            }else{
                posToTop=0;
                $('#bg-'+lastBg).animate({
                    height:hWin+'px',
                    top:4320+'px'
                },600);
            }
        }
        //--Scroll to the bottom for credits page
        if(currentNav==(navArray.length-1)){
            $('html,body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(document).height()
            }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
        }
    }
}
/**
 *  Retrac the background to normal
 */
function retractBg(){
    var hWin = $(window).height();
    if(resizeBg && lastheight>0 && lastBg!=""){
        $('#bg-'+lastBg).css({'z-index':0});
        //trace('posToTop callback : '+posToTop + ' lastBg :  ' +  lastBg + '  lastheight : ' +lastheight);
        if(posToTop>0){
            //trace('reset pos top : ' + posToTop);
            $('#bg-'+lastBg).animate({
                height:lastheight+'px',
                top:lastPosToTop+'px'
            },600)
        }else{
            $('#bg-'+lastBg).animate({
                height:lastheight+'px'
            },600)
        }
    }
}
```