# jquery prevent normal scroll and animate

Tags: jquery, scroll

Basically I am looking for a way to recreate the scrolling feature on this website

http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9

The thing is that when you begin scrolling, the page doesn't scroll as usual, but it notices your scrolling command and animates a vertical page shift. Does anybody know how to recreate that feature in jQuery?

I assume that it would be something about `e.preventDefault();` when `$(window).scroll()` and then perform an animation that slides the current div up or down based on the height of the window.

Comment: the page is scrolling fine..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy :) Nothing is wrong with the scrolling. But You will notice that when you use the wheel, it is not like that the webpage follow the exact movements of your finger. It simply confirms that you want to scroll up or down and then animate the positioning of the divs.

Comment: it is definitely true your website is using third party script js which is preventing default scroll..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control page scroll animation with mousewheel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171828/control-page-scroll-animation-with-mousewheel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I made something that should fit your needs:

```
var page = $("div.page");
var heights = [];
var index = 0;

page.each(function(i){
    heights[i] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    // normalize the wheel delta
    delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;

    // do nothing if is already animating
    if($("html,body").is(":animated")) return false;

    // increase the page index based on wheel direction
    index = (index-delta) % (heights.length);

    // animate the scrolling
    $("html,body").stop().animate({
        scrollTop: heights[index]
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/7TKmc/2/

Comment: WOW!! This is nice.. thanks man.. Only one thing though.. It only seems to work in IE (Which suprises me a lot, since IE usually sucks).. I am on a Mac and neither Chrome nor Safari make the animation as IE..

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Mhh, I'm on chrome, latest stable release. Works well! You can use Brandon Aarons mousewheel plugin. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/7TKmc/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at their js file here:  http://beoplay.com/layouts/SBV-Custom/HMProductPage/js/src/BeoplayA9_min.js

If you unminify it and take a look at the code starting at line 3444 - you'll see that they are using [jQuery.event.fixHooks](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) to create and respond to custom events (`["DOMMouseScroll", "mousewheel"]`).

They are then able to read the mousewheel movement and manually scroll the page based on that.

If you grab the scrollbar of the page, the scroll happens normally - so it's just the mousewheel that "animates a vertical page shift".

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

- Use a mousewheel plugin, I recommend [this plugin](https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js).
- Bind `mousewheel` to the `html` or `body`. 
  `$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {})`
  DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ukotit/48/edit
- Based on `delta` (1 = up, -1 = down), use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/).

Hope this helps!