# jquery scroller mousewheel with keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a site that is a scroller 
Here is the article i am trying to add the keyboard keys up and down to below code

[http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/r3x7r/1/]

[Control page scroll animation with mousewheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171828/control-page-scroll-animation-with-mousewheel/16516694#16516694)

kindly any one let me know if this is possible..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

http://jsfiddle.net/r3x7r/274

Added keyboard shortcut for scrolling in the page sections.

```
// OUR CODE
var winH = $(window).height();
$('.page').height(winH);

var c = 0;
var pagesN = $('.page').length;

var activePage=0;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(ev, delta) {

    delta>0 ? --c : ++c ;    
    if(c===-1){
        c=0;
    }else if(c===pagesN){
        c=pagesN-1;
    }
    activePage = c;
    var pagePos = $('.page').eq(c).position().top;       
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos},{easing: 'easeInCirc', duration: 1200});
    return false; 

});

$(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.which == 40) {
        activePage = activePage+1;
        var pagePos = $('.page').eq(activePage).position().top;       
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos},{easing: 'easeInCirc', duration: 1200});
    } else if(event.which == 38) {
        activePage = activePage-1;
        var pagePos = $('.page').eq(activePage).position().top;       
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos},{easing: 'easeInCirc', duration: 1200});
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for - can it be modified for the way it is set up in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/r3x7r/102/

Comment: @Kasper Bjerre You want me add the keyboard event for the provided fiddle '/102'?

Comment: that would be awesome :) - The fiddle is made by roXon, and I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171828/control-page-scroll-animation-with-mousewheel

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle, [http://jsfiddle.net/r3x7r/275/](http://jsfiddle.net/r3x7r/275/)

Comment: thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. There seems to be a problem if switching between mousewheel and arrow-keys though - if you starte out with arrow keys, and then switch to the mousewheel (or the other way around) it loses track of what section you are currently at.
I am also trying to start out at section two - which works out fine with an anchor - but gives me the same problem: the navigation does not "know" where on the page I am when I navigates afterwards.