# Javascript: scroll from one div to the other when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to be able, when scrolling down, to go directly to the next div, and when scrolling up, to go directly to the previous div.
Here are my files with an example with two divs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;

  function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
      return [curtop];
    }
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#space_od").offset().top
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#black_hole").offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#black_hole {
  background-image: url("black_hole.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#space_od {
  background-image: url("2001.png");
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="black_hole">
</div>
<div id="space_od">
</div>
```

It seems to work fine when scrolling down the first time, but not when scrolling up, it seems to move a few pixels and then stop. Any ideas?

Comment: I've had to do this several times and have never seen a concise implementation. This library has worked well for me: https://github.com/zynga/scroller. This one, https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll, is also popular on GitHub but I don't like the API as much.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171828/control-page-scroll-animation-with-mousewheel

Comment: **Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/r3x7r/410/**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scrollTo` is a class to add to the divs you need to scroll to:

```
<div id="black_hole" class="scrollTo">

</div>
<div id="space_od" class="scrollTo">

</div>
```

Js

```
var scrolling = false;
var currentPos = 0;

    function scrollUp(){
        if(!scrolling && currentPos > 0 ){
            scrolling=true;
            currentPos --;
            var scrollToElement = $('.scrollTo')[currentPos];

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(scrollToElement).offset().top
            }, 500, function(){
                scrolling = false;
            });      
        }
    }   

    function scrollDown(){   
        if(!scrolling && currentPos < $('.scrollTo').length-1  ){
            scrolling=true;
            currentPos ++;
            var scrollToElement = $('.scrollTo')[currentPos];

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(scrollToElement).offset().top
            }, 500,function(){
                scrolling = false;
            }); 
        }
    }    

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Get the current position on load

        for( var i = 0; i < $('.scrollTo').length; i++){
            var elm = $('.scrollTo')[i];

            if( $(document).scrollTop() >= $(elm).offset().top ){
                currentPos = i;
            }
        }

        $(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                scrollDown();
            }else {
                scrollUp();   
            }
            return false;
        });

        $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                scrollDown();
            }else {
                scrollUp();     
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just noticed something, what happens if there are more divs?

Comment: I changed the beginning to: var currentPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
But, when scrolling down, it goes up in the beginning, and then when I scroll down again, it goes down... Strange...

Comment: currentPos should be an integer. 0 for the first div, 1 for the second, n for the last if there are (n+1) divs with the scrollTo class

Comment: This seems to do the trick:var currentPos = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)/$(window).height();

Comment: I've found a different solution that should work, please check the updated answer, I've added a few lines inside  $(document).ready() method