# Change the position of the screen with once movement of scrolling bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

HelloI have made two div that the height of each one cover the hole page.These two div are located below of each other.I want when user lowering the scroll bar of the mouse the page directly go to begining of second div And when raising the scroll bar the page directly go to beginning of first div.Please help me to understand how to this 
Thank you very much.

```css
#up_page{
width:100%;
height:50%;
background-color:red;
}
#down_page{
width:100%;
height:50%;
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 1500px;">
  <div id="up_page"> 
  </div>
  <div id="down_page"> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another thread, which had the same problems as yours.

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905765/javascript-scroll-from-one-div-to-the-other-when-scrolling)

```
        var winH = $(window).height();
        $('.page').height(winH);

        var c = 0;
        var pagesN = $('.page').length;
        var canScroll = true;

        $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(ev, delta) {
         ev.preventDefault();
         if(!canScroll) return;
         delta>0 ? --c : ++c ;    
         if(c===-1){
         c=0;
         }else if(c===pagesN){
          c=pagesN-1;
         }
         canScroll = false;
           var pagePos = $('.page').eq(c).position().top;       
          $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos},700,     
      
         function(){
         canScroll = true;
         });
         return false; 

         });
```

Here is an example of how it would look with some jQuery:

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3x7r/410)

Hope this is what you were looking for.