# jquery nth child to root

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).click(function(){
  var i = 1;
  $("p:nth-child("+i+")").scrollintoview();
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollintoview/1.8/jquery.scrollintoview.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have here this code. I'm trying to make a search feature on every click. How can I search for these paragraphs one by one on every click with this structure of html. Is there any selector that will treat the ".parent" class as the parent element of these paragraphs? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: You're setting `i` to `1` every time you call the function. Then you never use it. If you want to remember something between calls, it should be a global variable.

Comment: where are you using your i?

Comment: All your paragraphs are the first child in their respective divs, so `p:nth-child(1)` matches all of them.

Comment: I suspect what you want is `$("p").eq(i)`.

Comment: Or maybe `$(".parent div").eq(i).find("p")`

Comment: I've already edited the snippet. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare `i` as a global.Then only its increment the value
2. And use jquery [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function its match the `p` index
3. And target with `.parent p`
4. Do with class add and remove for switching color

**Updated** with switching color

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).click(function(){
  $('.parent').find("p").removeClass('yellow').eq(i).addClass('yellow')
  i++;
});
```

```css
.yellow{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this almost do the trick. Is it possible to shift that highlight from one p to another?

Comment: Thank you. But what if i want to scroll from one p to another? Sorry for not stating the main purpose on the problem. I'll edit it.

Comment: check this answer .It will same as you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803901/how-to-scroll-to-next-div-using-javascript/54804025#54804025

Comment: Will check that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Select all the paragraph elements and on click using i highlight them one by one

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).click(function() {
$('p').css("background-color", "")
  $(Object.values($("p"))[i]).css("background-color", "yellow");
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this almost do the trick. Is it possible to shift that highlight from one p to another?

Comment: Thank you. But what if i want to scroll from one p to another? Sorry for not stating m main purpose on the problem. I'll edit it.

Comment: scroll animation??

Comment: Yes. If possible.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905765/javascript-scroll-from-one-div-to-the-other-when-scrolling